# css adjacent selector with nested element and :after

Tags: asp.net, css

This is the OLD HTML

```
<div class="MainClass">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ppp" id="ppp" class="subClassInput">
    <label for="subClassLabel"></label>
</div>
```

This is the NEW HTML:

```
<div class="MainClass">
    <span class="subClassInput">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ppp" id="ppp">
    </span>
    <label for="subClassLabel"></label>
</div>
```

my css was working fine but I want to work with asp.net which renders the asp:CheckBox with spans around it.
I guess I can build a special control and override that, but I'd rather just fix my CSS.

so, to get to the label after checking the input worked fine like that:

```
.MainClass input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
 //attributes
 }
```

but now I don't know how to reach the label after the input was checked.

Thanks

Comment: Can you drop the `span.subClassInput` or do you need it?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this, unfortunately. You can't go back up the tree with CSS selectors. Your only option is to use javascript.

Comment: @ChrisHardie, thank you, this is so disappointing to hear.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that? i thought maybe addressing the label first with :before and then handling the span+input. will that work?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently possible to do `<` or `:parent` selectors in CSS or CSS3. Otherwise you could have done something like this:

```
span < input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
```

or perhaps

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked:parent + label:after
```

Read this http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked for a script solution, here is one. Note I am leveraging the jQuery library, you will need to include it.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
             var label = $(this).parent().siblings('label');
             //apply your CSS styles here
          }
    });
});
```